# Starting a new activity inside a thread

Tags: android

I have a question about threads. I'm not sure what is happening here. My understanding is that the progress dialog won't end until the long activity has finished, but that is not what is happening. I want the long activity to start, finish, dismiss the spinner, and then start the new activity with the intent.

```
 final ProgressDialog spinnerDialog = ProgressDialog.show(  
                MainScreen.this, "",  
                "Waiting for accurate (> 10 meters) GPS coordinates...Please wait. ", true);  
            new Thread(new Runnable() {  
                public void run() {  
                    //Do something that takes a while
                    spinnerDialog.dismiss();  
                    return;  
                }  
            }).start();

              Intent tvi = new Intent();
              tvi.setClass(getInstance(), TabbedView.class);
              startActivity(tvi);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new activity should be done in the main (UI) thread. But just writing the code after starting the new thread won't guarantee that you have all the information you need to create your intent. I recommend using a handler

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    handler = new Handler();
    startprogress();
}

public void startProgress(View view) {
    // Do something long
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do long stuff (like getting info for intent)
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //make new intent
                //start new activity with intent you just made
            }
        });
        }
    }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

}

and more importantly, here is the link to the developers page on handlers:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: how can I do this with a progressdialog?